# Away3d - load model with bones

Tags: actionscript-3, 3dsmax, away3d

I’m trying to create simple model in 3dsmax. My model is just a square with two bones.

I wonder how to export it (whatever format), import to Away3d and control the bones.

I know that it’s must load a skeleton and get the bones by a name.
I was trying to use Prefab, but it didn’t work.

Any ideas or examples will very usefull.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look [here](https://code.google.com/p/awd/wiki/3dsMax)

Comment: .awd format should work fine. What problem are you getting, simply use  Prefab to export to .awd and then use AssetLibrary to load the model and bones to your scene. Or you can use the 3ds max 2012 awd exporter? Please specify your problem in more details. Also, you might want to have a look around at away3d forums and examples.